# Scan memory of external process in windows with Python 3

Tags: python, readprocessmemory

I've been trying doing this for days without any success, so I hope that someone can help me.

My goal is to scan the memory of a process once I have the pid, and actually read the strings of that process.

For example I want to do something like this.

Let's say that I have a notepad open and the pid is = 4578.
I want first to check if in the process memory there is the string "cold water", if the string is in the memory then I would do a deeper scan extracting all the strings in the memory, otherwise I wouldnt.

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes
import psutil
import time

def get_client_pid(process_name):
    pid = None
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == process_name:
            pid = int(proc.pid)
            print("Found, PID = ", pid)
            break
    return pid

pid = get_client_pid("notepad.exe.exe")

PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010

process = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ,False,pid)
readprocess = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
rdbuf = ctypes.c_uint()
bytread = ctypes.c_size_t()
base = 0x00400000
for addr in range(base, base + 11):
    try:
        if readprocess(process, ctypes.c_void_p(addr), ctypes.byref(rdbuf), ctypes.sizeof(rdbuf),ctypes.byref(bytread)):
            print(rdbuf.value)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR", e)
```

This is an example code I found somewhere and edited a bit.

How can I know all the addresses in memory that belong to a specific process?

is a better or simpler module than ctypes to do this?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have some typing errors. Try replacing this code:

```
pid = get_client_pid("notepad.exe.exe")
```

With this one:

```
pid = get_client_pid("notepad.exe")
```